# How to iteratively change div background image using image paths stored in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a index.html where `headerwrap` div's css property is defined in css file which is included in index.html

HTML

```
<div id="headerwrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#headerwrap {
background: url(../img/portfolio/img1.jpg) center top;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top:120px;
text-align:center;
background-attachment: relative;
background-position: center center;

width: 100%;
bottom: 10px;
```

}

I have written a js function `change_image` to change image of div `headerwrap`

```
var image_array= ['url("../img/portfolio/img2.jpg")', 'url("../img/portfolio/img3.jpg")', 'url("../img/portfolio/img4.jpg")'];
var image_index = 0;

var change_image = function(){

    $('#headerwrap').css("background", image_array[image_index]);  
    image_index++;
    if (image_index >= image_array.length){
        image_index = 0;
    }
}

$(document).ready( function(){

    setInterval(change_image, 5000);

 });
```

`change_image` function is getting called after every 5 sec as when i see the div with firebug it looks like this

```
<div id="headerwrap" style="background: url("../img/portfolio/img3.jpg") repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After 5 sec div background is white and i cant see the 1st image. What changes i need to do so that i can see image rotation

Comment: what do you mean by rotation ?

Comment: Rotate background images given in image_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, this don't work.
Use some class style and in js change class style.

CSS:
    #headerwrap {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top:120px;
    text-align:center;
    background-attachment: relative;
    background-position: center center;

```
width: 100%;
bottom: 10px;

}
.background1 {
background-image: url(../img/portfolio/img1.jpg);
}
.background2 {
background-image: url(../img/portfolio/img2.jpg);
}
```

JS:

```
var class_array= ['background1', 'background2'];
var image_index = 0;

var change_image = function(){
$('#headerwrap').removeClass(class_array.join(' '));
    $('#headerwrap').addClass(image_array[image_index]);  
    image_index++;
    if (image_index >= image_array.length){
        image_index = 0;
    }
}

$(document).ready( function(){

    setInterval(change_image, 5000);

});
```

Enjoy your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put the full URL (or relative to the page or site) in the the image_array.  When you use a relative url for a background image (`url('../foo.png')`) in a CSS file the `../` is relative to the CSS file.  However, when you set with javascript it is relative to the current page URL.

Comment: i have defined tree folder "css" for css file, "js" for js file and "img" for img files so all folder are at same level

Comment: yes but your file (*the html one*) is not. So try `url('/img/portfolio/img2.jpg')` for array images

Comment: @question, are you running your page from a server or just opening the html file from the disk ? and where is the html file in relation to the `img` folder?

Comment: i am opening it directly and file structure is like project/index.html, css/style.css, js/custom.js, img/portfolio

Comment: When you say "open directly" do you mean via a URL or via file open from web browser?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for changing background image is as below:

```
$('#element').css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
```

Use:

```
$('#headerwrap').css("background-image", image_array[image_index]);
```

Image array should have : `url(/path)` and not `url('/path')`

`var image_array= ['url(./img/portfolio/img3.jpg)', 'url(./img/portfolio/img2.jpg)', 'url(./img/portfolio/img4.jpg)'];`

Comment: Verified when i used same url in css its working but when i used this url in js its working

Comment: There might be two reasons for it. 1. `url('/path..')` should be `url(/path)` without inner quotes. 2. CSS file might have different path structure.

Comment: ok what can i do is move all images in same folder where js file is then it will work

Comment: I Used like this `var image_array= [url(../img/portfolio/img3.jpg), url(../img/portfolio/img2.jpg), url(../img/portfolio/img4.jpg)];`

Comment: NO!! Use this `var image_array= ['url(./img/portfolio/img3.jpg)', 'url(./img/portfolio/img2.jpg)', 'url(./img/portfolio/img4.jpg)'];`

Comment: Didnt worked, do i need to run these files on server. I am directly opening the file in browser

Answer (score 0):

you're using the wrong quotes -

```
style="background: url("../img/portfolio/img3.jpg")
```

the style attribute is now just "background: url(" so it isn't loading.

the elements in your image_array in the js should use these quotes.

```
"url('../img/portfolio/img2.jpg')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
#headerwrap {
background-image: url(/img/portfolio/img1.jpg);
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top:120px;
text-align:center;
background-attachment: relative;
background-position: center center;

width: 100%;
bottom: 10px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var image_array= ['url(/img/portfolio/img2.jpg)', 'url(/img/portfolio/img3.jpg)', 'url("../img/portfolio/img4.jpg")'];
var image_index = 0;

var change_image = function(){

    $('#headerwrap').css("background-image", image_array[image_index]);  
    image_index++;
    if (image_index >= image_array.length){
        image_index = 0;
    }
}

$(document).ready( function(){

    setInterval(change_image, 5000);

});
```

**EDIT**
Changed the image urls to absolute instead of relative for consistency.

Comment: If i am using background-image in css then 1st image is not getting rendered

Comment: The url provided in the CSS file needs to be relative to the CSS file itself, not the page running it.

Comment: I usually use absolute urls starting at the domain, everywhere. `/img/portfolio/img1.jpg`.